# Firefox 51 Flagging HTTP Login, solution for SSL?

Tags: wordpress, firefox, ssl

I have a CMS that I've developed similar to wordpress that is geared for small businesses. Typically one user uses the system to make changes. Recently Firefox 51 is displaying a notice that says "This connection is not secure. Logins entered here could be compromised. Learn More"

I have deployed this CMS on numerous websites. Now, from what I see, Firefox wants me to install an SSL on each one of these? This really isn't practical or is it? Is there really a threat? Now I feel like my users will be scared and deter them from using the system.

Is this an issue for wordpress users? Is there a relatively simple solution?

[image]

This is the reply I got from Host Gator regarding support for Let's Encrypt

> While our System Administrators are certainly looking at the
>   opportunity to incorporate open SSL certificates in the shared
>   environment I do not currently have a time line to implementation. As
>   of now if you requested us to install a Let's Encrypt SSL Certificate
>   it would be treated as a 3rd Party Installation and incur a $10 fee.
>   Additionally, though I understand this may not be an ideal solution,
>   you would be able to perform these installations and attempt to
>   configure the automatic renewals on a hosting package with root level
>   access, such as a VPS or dedicated server.

I want to also note that I have a dreamhost account and it took only the click of a button to add and SSL to a domain. So easy, really hope to see other host's follow suit.

Comment: Having users enter sensitive information like login data on a non-https page is considered bad practice. And what's "unpractical" about having https everywhere? That stuff has gotten considerably easier with the latest generation webservers, TLS/SNI and Letsencrypt.

Comment: Almost all of the sites using the CMS are on a Host Gator re-seller account. To install SSL requires a dedicated IP per domain, which they bill at $50/yr. That's what seems impractical to me.

Comment: No, look up TLS/SNI. Needing a dedicated IP just to support https is a thing of the past.

Comment: So in my case, using Host Gator which does not support Let's encrypt could you give me a short explanation how this would work and how I would implement?

Comment: I have no idea whether hostgator supports sni (have you asked?), but I would think that nowadays most hosters actually do support it, just to be able to host multiple https sites from 1 ip address. If your current hoster doesn't, maybe it's time to move on.

Answer (score 1):

SSL is now fairly easy to obtain or add to your sites, most of the hosting provider supports AUTOSSL in WHM panel which is free and you can add ssl to each of your domains by just clicking or you can also install [Let’s Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/). You'll just need a hosting provider to support it.

While you can ssh to your host and install letsencrypt and automatically renew those certs every 3 months.

But in your case if you are using hostgator, you can obtain [StartSSL Free](https://www.startssl.com/Support?v=1) cert, you can generate your Class 1 certificate for free for a year then follow their guide on [how to install third-party ssl certs hostgator?](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/how-do-i-use-the-third-party-ssl-certificate-i-purchased) .

Comment: I have access to WHM and there is an option to "Generate an SSL Certificate and Signing Request". However, from what I can tell I would still have to pay host gator to install this and apparently on their form they still require a dedicated IP $48/yr plus $10 install fee https://secure.hostgator.com/installssl.php . It seems to me that Host Gator is behind the times and needs to add an option for Let's Encrypt?

Answer (score 0):

Firefox and Chrome have added those notifications to HTTP screens that have login forms.

You really should add SSL certificates to your sites. [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) makes the whole process pretty dang easy. If you don't want to, or don't have the technical know-how, using a free [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) account with flexible SSL enabled will do the job as well.

Comment: It doesn't look like Host Gator supports Let's Encrypt. Also, does that require a dedicated IP to work?

Comment: You should be able to use CloudFlare without a dedicated IP. The service walks you through how to get it set up when you sign up for it. Basically, you would change a couple settings in Hostgator, and users would begin accessing your site "through" CloudFlare first. CloudFlare would then layer an SSL certificate on it to upgrade the HTTP connection to HTTP – thereby removing that warning.

Comment: @Leland, while Cloudflare's Flexible SSL may help the OP in this case, it should be noted that it [does not provide a true encrypted tunnel](https://www.itsupportguides.com/knowledge-base/website-tips/why-cloudflares-flexible-ssl-is-really-bad/). Specifically Cloudflare's connection to the site's server is not encrypted, and [they stress](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170416-What-do-the-SSL-options-mean-) that it should not be used for situations where sensitive information is being passed.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable that message going on `about:config`, search `insec`, than double-click the line `security.insecure_field_warning.contextual.enabled`
This will set that option to `false` and you won't display that message anymore.